# How to launch an interactive view of a table after file dialog in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, datatable, triggers, pyqt5, widget

Using PyQt5, I made two widgets. The first widget is a user-prompt to select a file with an alert that confirms the selected filepath. The `BackEnd` reads the selected data file and processes the data; for the sake of MWE, `data` is defined in `BackEnd` as a 2-d array and the selected file is only used to get a filepath. The second widget loads a view of the table for the user to look at. (It is not yet relevant to this question, but my use case is that I would like to have a user to select rows/columns by clicking on particular cells.) **I can get the second widget to work by itself, but the table does not load if I first load the first widget.** I don't think I am missing any `.close()` or `.exec_()` methods, so I'm not sure why the second widget will not load. What is the cause of this error and how do I circumvent it? I tried using `on_clicked()` methods in previous attempts, but I'm not sure how to apply that to different types of widgets/tables/etc that are not identical.

The code below is for the table-view of the 2-d array.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np

class BackEnd():

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        nrows, ncols = 50, 10
        self.data = np.arange(nrows * ncols).reshape((nrows, ncols)).astype(str)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    """
    An instance of this class is created inside the constructor
    of the class 'TableWindow'.
    """

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])

class TableWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    """
    This class is used to view the raw data file via gui.
    """

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setWindowTitle("Select 'row' if each student corresponds to a row; otherwise, select 'column'")
```

By running the code snippet below, one should be able to see a pop-up showing a view of the table (second widget).

```
back_end = BackEnd()

## initialize application
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

## view data file
window = TableWindow(back_end.data.tolist())
window.show()

## exit application
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When trying to combine the two widgets, the code snippet above should be commented out. The code below is for the file selection widget (first widget).

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    """
    This class contains all GUI methods.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._backend = BackEnd()
        self._fpath = None
        super().__init__()
        self.initialize_ui()

    @property
    def backend(self):
        return self._backend

    @property
    def fpath(self):
        return self._fpath

    def initialize_ui(self):
        self.select_input_data_file()
        self.verify_input_data_file()
        # self.close()
        self.interact_with_table()

    def select_input_data_file(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(
            self,
            "Select input file",
            "path",
            "",
            supportedSchemes=["file"],
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        fpath = dialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file', '/home')[0]
        self._fpath = fpath
        # dialog.close()
        # dialog = None

    def verify_input_data_file(self):
        alert = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        alert.setText('The input filepath you selected is: \n{}'.format(self.fpath))
        alert.exec_()
        # alert.close()
        # alert = None

    def interact_with_table(self):
        window = TableWindow(self.backend.data.tolist())
        window.show()
```

The code below is my attempt at having the user use the first widget to select a file (successful) and then show the data table (unsuccessful).

```
## initialize application
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

## view data file
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

## exit application
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MainWindow.interact_with_table`, the `TableWindow` widget is assigned to a local variable. When `interact_with_table` returns, this variable goes out of scope and the reference count of `TableWindow` goes to zero. This will cause the `TableWindow` object to be deleted during the next garbage collection cycle. One solution is to make a persistant reference to the table window for example by assigning it to an instance variable of `MainWindow`, i.e.

```
def interact_with_table(self):
    self.table_window = TableWindow(self.backend.data.tolist())
    self.table_window.show()
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense - thanks! I notice that the original window is not closed when the table pops up; adding `self.close()` inside `def interact_with_table(self)` has no effect. Is it possible to close this original window such that a new window can be launched from `MainWindow` at a later point?

Comment: You could not show the original window in the first place by removing the line `window.show()` after `window = MainWindow()` in the main script. The main window is empty anyway so there is nothing to show.