# PyQt5 App: third widget doesn't show up at runtime, however it is visible in Debug Mode (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this app which starts with a QMainWindow. Upon choosing suitable locations (directories) for databases and stuff, it allows the user to start the setup of a PLC controller, which is hosted on a second window (QWidget). No problems so far.

While the second (SetupWindow) builds up it also checks a series of xml files parsing them, building dictionaries and stuff.

If an error is encountered while parsing I want to catch it, stop the Setup Window from finishing to populate tables, lists, and the likes, and popup a third window instead, showing the parsing error and giving the possibility to the user to edit the bad XML and fix it (launching a text editor of choice).

Everything works fine with each module in a void (the widgets reside on different modules).
When I put it all together, in the case of a Parsing exception, the third window does not show, and the app continues populating the second window (partially at that, since some XML were skipped for bad format, that is the exceptions I am trying to catch).

The weird thing is that when I tried to debug it from PyCharm, breaking at the exception and then stepping in, **the third window then pops up regularly**. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code (Note: I use [QTDesigner](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) to set the UI layouts) .

First MainWindow (Abstract: clicking event of a button to start the Setup):

```
def setupOnClick(self):
    config['active']['old_gui'] = self.ui.GUI_old_proj_path_textline.text()
    config['active']['controllers'] = self.ui.controllers_files_path_textline.text()
    config['active']['proj_dest'] = self.ui.dest_folder_textline.text()
    config_name = os.path.join(this_app_path, 'config.ini')
    with open(config_name, "w") as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)
    import SetupControllers
    self.setupWin = SetupControllers.MainWindow(config,
                                                config_name,
                                                self.main_icon,
                                                MainWindow.CurProJectName)
```

This is the second window (SetupControllers):

```
from lib.SearchControllers import get_controller_dict  # this is an external module where I stuff various functions
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

myForm_2, baseClass = uic.loadUiType('./forms/setup.ui')
class MainWindow(baseClass):
    def __init__(self, config_obj: ConfigParser,
                 config_name: str,
                 icon:  qtg.QIcon(),
                 proj_name: str,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = myForm_2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.setWindowTitle(proj_name + " Setup")
        self.root_path = self.config_obj['active']['controllers']
        # doing some more init stuff
        # .........................
        self.load_bulk()   # starting to parse xml dbase to populate the various widgets
        self.show
```

Here is where the parsing function is called from:

```
def load_bulk(self):
    # get the list of running components into a dictionary
    for i in self.list_controllers:
        i_path = os.path.join(self.root_path, i)
        self.components[i] = get_controller_dict(i_path,
                                                 self.config_obj,
                                                 'Application.xml',
                                                 'Subcomponents/Subcomponent',
                                                 'Name',
                                                 'src')
```

Here is the parsing function, where I want to trap the exception:

```
import lib.parsingError as PE
def get_controller_dict(controller_path: str,
                        config: ConfigParser,
                        target: str,
                        inner_element: str,
                        tag_key: str,
                        tag_value: str,
                        tag_value_2: str=None):
    gc_dict = {}
    cdp_app_file = os.path.join(controller_path, target)
    if not os.path.exists(cdp_app_file):
        return gc_dict
    try:
        root = ET.parse(cdp_app_file).getroot()
        for type_tag in root.findall(inner_element):
            gc_dict[type_tag.attrib[tag_key]] = type_tag.attrib[tag_value]
    except ET.ParseError as ex: # debug breakpoint is here
        parseErr = PE.MainWindow(config, ex, cdp_app_file)
    except Exception as ex:
        show_exception(f"Parsing {cdp_app_file}", ex)
    return gc_dict
```

Finally this is the PE.parsing error. Again, this also resides in its own module:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from configparser import ConfigParser
myForm_3, baseClass = uic.loadUiType('./forms/parseErr.ui')
class MainWindow(baseClass):
    def __init__(self, config_obj: ConfigParser,
                 exc: ET.ParseError,
                 filename: str,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # your code begins here
        self._icon = qtg.QIcon()
        self.ui = myForm_3()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.MM_logo.setPixmap(qtg.QPixmap(':/logo_Small.png'))
        self.main_icon = qtg.QIcon()
        self.main_icon.addPixmap(qtg.QPixmap(':/logo_Small.png'), qtg.QIcon.Normal, qtg.QIcon.Off)
        self.setWindowIcon(self.main_icon)
        self.exc = exc
        self.config = config_obj
        self.filename = filename
        self.setLabels()
        self.ui.OK_butt.clicked.connect(self.ok_onClick)
        self.ui.validate_butt.clicked.connect(self.validate_onClick)
        self.ui.editXml_butt.clicked.connect(self.editXML)
        # your code ends here
        self.show()
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is a bit too articulate, and trying to understand what is going on is really hard. I suggest you to patiently try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (which could probably help you solve the problem on your own), as I doubt anybody could be actually able to help you right now. Also note that using `uic.loadUiType` is only required under certain conditions, and you can directly call `uic.loadUi('somefile.ui', self)` right after the `__init__`.

Comment: I suspect your issue is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265787/how-to-launch-an-interactive-view-of-a-table-after-file-dialog-in-pyqt5/67277977#67277977). In this case the issue is likely caused by the fact that `passErr` is a local variable of `get_controller_dict`. It would also explain why the window is shown in the debugger because `passErr` is still in scope at the breakpoint.

Comment: @Heike: spot-on. Thnx a lot. at the moment I just patched it `returning` the widget instead of assigning to `passErr`. And now the window shows up. I'll fix it better later on, but that was awesome. You can write it on the answers and I'll check it out, else I'll do it